# How to assert that an exception is caught?

Tags: java, junit, exception

I know how to assert that an Exception is thrown. But, how can I assert that an Exception was thrown and it was successfully caught? For example, say I have a method which should throw a particular type of exception for invalid inputs

```
public static void myMethod(String value) {
    try {
        someExternalMethod(value);// can throw IllegalArgumentException
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Let me handle it differently");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Not IllegalArgumentException");
    }
}
```

Now I want to assert that for some values the method indeed has thrown 'IllegalArgumentException' and not some other Exception.

Comment: How about first testing that `someExternalMethod` throws the exception, and then that `myMethod` does not, for the same input?

Comment: You can mock method to throw exception.

Comment: @tobias_k: Though I have written for simplicity as `someExternalMethod`, the way I call the actual method is bit different, I am using some deep retry strategy, using Executors to call it. But I get your valid point, may be I have to change my way of testing if I have no other option

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of testing `myMethod` you cannot (and more importantly, you should not want to) check that `someExternalMethod` has thrown `IllegalArgumentException`. In fact, your tests of `myMethod` should not assume that a call of `someExternalMethod` has been made: it is an implementation detail of `myMethod`.

The very reason `myMethod` catches these exceptions is to hide them from its callers. You should check that these exceptions are hidden from you by passing values that cause them, and verifying that nothing is thrown in both cases.

Testing `someExternalMethod`, along with the exceptions that it throws, is the task accomplished by testing `someExternalMethod`, not `myMethod`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the important point of unit testing - **tests should test *behaviour*, not *implementation*.**

Given this assumption you should be testing the behaviour of `myMethod` is as expected when an `IllegalArgumentException` occurs.  It's hard to say any more than that with the method you've shown given the parameter, a single `String` is immutable, there is no return value and no exceptions are thrown.

A better example might be this method (which is a little contrived to demonstrate the point):

```
public double divide(int numerator, int denominator)
{
  try
  {
    return numerator / denominator;
  }
  catch (ArithmeticException e)
  {
    return Double.NaN;
  }
}
```

Where your tests would assert that the division is correct and that when an error occurs `NaN` is returned, like this:

```
@Test
public void testDivide()
{
  assertEquals(2.0, divide(4, 2), 0);
}

@Test
public void testDivideByZero()
{
  assertTrue(Double.isNaN(divide(1, 0));
}
```

You could then re-write the `divide` method like this:

```
public double divide(int numerator, int denominator)
{
  if (denominator == 0)
  {
    return Double.NaN;
  }
  else
  {
    return numerator / denominator;
  }
}
```

And the tests would confirm the operation of my system because the behaviour of the `divide` method remains unchanged.

Comment: Isn't 'Nan' not equal to itself?

Comment: @C.R. actually scratch that, playing with the example in an IDE, the logic wasn't quite right (I did say it was slightly contrived to demonstrate the point) and it should be `Double.isNaN` used in the assertion

Answer (score 0):

`catch` blocks are evaluated in the order they are.

Your code works fine: in case of `IllegalArgumentException`, `Exception` block will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mock method `someExternalMethod(value)` to force throw `Exception`
2. Test method `myMethod`, checking that is not throwing Exception:

   ```
   @Test
   public void testMyMethod() {
      try {
         myMethod("value");
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         Assert.fail();
      }
   }
   ```